# Is there a way to create parquet file from xml/json input file without .avsc file and without impala/hive.?

Tags: parquet

I want to convert my input file (xml/json) to parquet. I have already have one solution that works with spark, and creates required parquet file.

However, due to other client requirements,  i might need to create a solution that does not involve hadoop eco system such as hive, impala, spark or mapreduce.

And, Kite SDK is using .avsc file to create parquet data, kindly correct me if i am wrong. I might be short sighted but, looks like it needs avro schema file. So, is there any library that can create parquet file from self explanatory files such as xml or json.?

**Note:** If it feels like not a proper approach, i would like to understand the reasons why it is not a recommended approach, so that i can earn some knowledge or understand the areas that i might have missed.

Comment: Parquet has its onw internal storage format, but for Serialization/Deserialization, records are transmitted either as AVRO objects, Protobuf objects, or Thrift objects. And Hive, Impala, Pig etc. **require AVRO**. Hence the AVRO schema definition file. You have no alternative. http://grepalex.com/2014/05/13/parquet-file-format-and-object-model/

Comment: oh.. Nice point samson.. It is so closely bound with spark, how does spark save them internally, spark does not ask for any schema to save, however, i i feel it can build one based on the dataframe schema. But, how does it save the data.?

Comment: You can read/write a Parquet file with AVRO bindings in plain old Java. Have a look at https://github.com/azkaban/azkaban-plugins/blob/master/plugins/hdfsviewer/src/azkaban/viewer/hdfs/ParquetFileViewer.java and https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-avro/src/test/java/parquet/avro/TestReadWrite.java -- the only dependencies against the Hadoop stack are because of HDFS. Just be careful to use "plain" AVRO types, because for example Hive stores TIMESTAMP and DECIMAL as `byte[]` with a non-trivial conversion :-/

Comment: Hi @SamsonScharfrichter, I am also doing some research on parquet. How did you find those information.? Is there any indepth book/article that gives complete in depth details on parquet..

Comment: Parquet is a work-in-progress, there is no definitive reference. And furthermore, anyone may use it in a custom way for custom requirements. E.g. you have to read the discussions in the JIRAs + the source code (cf. grepcode.com) to understand why & how the Hive committers have chosen to map the TIMESTAMP and DECIMAL types to AVRO byte arrays.

Comment: By the way, I am not fully convinced that Parquet is the alpha and omega of Big Data storage formats. ORC is real powerful when it comes to predicate pushdown for stripe pruning (à la Infobright, or Oracle Exadata, etc.) for massive scans. But of course, Parquet is sponsored by Cloudera and ORC is sponsored by HortonWorks. Now that Spark supports both formats I hope to see some benchmarks someday...

Comment: Thanks very much for the details @SamsonScharfrichter... Its a good learning experience. I do work a lot in spark and will definitely try benchmarks on those two formats..

Answer (score 2):

I just published one using python.

https://github.com/blackrock/xml_to_parquet

Convert one or more XML files into Apache Parquet format. Only requires a XSD and XML file to get started.

It requires a XSD schema file to convert everything in your XML file into an equivalent parquet file with nested data structures that match XML paths.

```
Convert a small XML file to a Parquet file
python xml_to_parquet.py -x PurchaseOrder.xsd PurchaseOrder.xml

INFO - 2021-01-21 12:32:38 - Parsing XML Files..
INFO - 2021-01-21 12:32:38 - Processing 1 files
DEBUG - 2021-01-21 12:32:38 - Generating schema from PurchaseOrder.xsd
DEBUG - 2021-01-21 12:32:38 - Parsing PurchaseOrder.xml
DEBUG - 2021-01-21 12:32:38 - Saving to file PurchaseOrder.xml.parquet
DEBUG - 2021-01-21 12:32:38 - Completed PurchaseOrder.xml
```