# Converting XML to Parquet - Nested objects and Lists

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parquet, amazon-athena

I have a requirement of converting `XML` Data into `Parquet` to be used in `S3`. It sounded like a simple problem at first and hence I hand coded the converter myself. But slowly as the data is getting complicated it is getting difficult to maintain the script. There are child objects that have 1-1 mapping with parent, that I would want to keep in the same parquet file and flatten the parent object. Some objects are list types and hence need to be normalized into multiple tables.

Is there really no simple way that converts an `XML` to `Parquet` and takes cares of child objects where child objects could be list objects that need a separate parquet for themselves.

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following converter, it requires the XSD as well so that you can define your schema upfront

https://github.com/blackrock/xml_to_parquet

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289548/is-there-a-way-to-create-parquet-file-from-xml-json-input-file-without-avsc-fil) out as well